# E79CDDB501B68E74DDF03EA4E75246A7FDF010D0: no identity found Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Tags: xcode, macos, codesign

I am facing codesign issue.

***I am using Xcode 6.0.1 and Os x server 3.2.1***

```
E79CDDB501B68E74DDF03EA4E75246A7FDF010D0: no identity found
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I tried all possible answers which are in Stack Overflow but i am unable to resolve this issue. Can anyone help me out with this issue. ??

The error log is as follows

```
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign E79CDDB501B68E74DDF03EA4E75246A7FDF010D0 --keychain /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Keychains/Portal.keychain --resource-rules=/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Caches/145dbe87fd1e5d8c0544850b54f3/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SocialCircles.app/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Caches/145dbe887fd1e5d8c0544850b54f34c8/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/SocialCircles.build/Debug-iphoneos/XXX.build/xxx.app.xcent /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Caches/145dbe887fd1e5d8c0544850b54f34c8/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/xxx.app
```

I checked `Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Keychains/Portal.keychain` through CL. It has only

```
r--------  1 _xcsbuildd  _xcs     86032 Oct 15 10:21 Portal.keychain​
```

I guess Portal.keychain should have codesign, xcodebuild also. I tried to import it using the answer provided in Stack Overflow by **seanwolter**

```
sudo security import "/Users/administrator/Desktop/someCertificate.p12" -P PASSWORD -k /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Keychains/Portal.keychain -A -T /usr/bin/codesign -T /usr/bin/xcodebuild -T /usr/bin/pkgbuild
```

but i am getting this error

security: SecKeychainItemImport: The specified keychain could not be found.

I dont know how to go about this issue. Please help me out...!!!

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25913665/adding-certificates-for-os-x-server-3-2-1-with-xcode-6-0-1

Answer (score 64):

I had the same issue. I fixed it through the following method :

```
Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > View Details > And just refresh the Provisioning Profile
```

Then `Restart the Xcode and Clean and Build.`

[image: View Details]

Comment: @Maximilian use the download all button

Answer (score 1):

in my case issue with provisioning profile shows expired date is not due, but when I checked in apple developer portal, and go to -iOS Provisioning Profiles, it shows me 
**Expires:
    Dec 04, 2015
Status:
    Invalid**

I have **created new development provisioning profile** for my app and downloaded from apple developer account. Then added in keychain Access and finally go to xCode project and selected new profile. And its solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I fixed it through the following method :

1. Go to developer account, double click on development or distribution certificate to add it to keychain (that depend on what kind of provision profile you need).
2. Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > View Details > And just refresh the Provisioning Profile (if you do not find your provision profile).
3. Clean and Build.