# Xcode's Bot always returns error

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, xcode-bots

I got an issue with Xcode's Bot. It always returns the "User canceled the operation. Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1" error string after running the command below:

```
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign <MY_PRIVATE_KEY> --entitlements /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Caches/2cdd321641e8c114e4eba9819b017479/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/MyApp.app.xcent /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Caches/2cdd321641e8c114e4eba9819b017479/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app
```

I can run this command in Terminal with sudo. I'm using Xcode 6.3.1 and OS X Server 4.1.53 in my Mac 10.10.4.

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a code signing error.  There are a few different reasons for this to happen so you will need to do some troubleshooting.  Can other bots build on your server?  If so then its probably a build settings issue in this specific project.

In the Xcode Project go to the `Project Target` that your trying to build, and then `Build Settings`, and `Code Signing`.  Under the `Provisioning Profile` you can either choose `Automatic` or explicitly choose the correct provision, and then under the `Code Signing Identity` choose iOS Developer.  This is probably where your issue is if its related to the project.  Do you have a proper provision setup for the project on the Apple Developer Portal?

If you can't get any bots to run on your server then the issue could be with how you set up Xcode Server.  Have you added the server to your team?  [Here](http://papaanton.com/setting-up-xcode-6-and-apple-server-4-0-for-continues-integration-with-cocoapods/) is the blog post that I used to get mine up and running, although you don't need to do all of those steps in the post.  Focus specifically on the *Setup Certificates* section and *Setup Provisioning Profiles* section.

Comment: Thanks @bolnad. I cannot run any bots successfully in my OS X Server. Although i can build and run my project with Xcode well. I think the Xcode server or OS X server don't have permission to run codesign. Also i tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30402861/xcode-server-build-multiple-matching-codesigning-identities-found and http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/ios-continous-integration-for-enterprise but it was not resolve. I will try your reference link now.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by copying the missing provisioning file from my local directory "/Users/phuongle/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles" to "/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/ProvisioningProfiles". Do not use the downloaded provisioning file from developer.apple.com directly.

I just want to note here for everyone having the same issue with me.